# Difficulty interpreting byte stream with pyserial when casting to floats

Tags: python, usb, pyserial

I'm using pyserial to get a data stream from a USB device.
When I use their proprietary software I get a plot updating and scrolling which looks like:

[image]

Very helpfully the manufacturers have given this info sheet:

[image]

So I've written code which to me seems completely logical and like it should work:

```
import serial
import struct

device = '/dev/cu.usbserial-DM003616' #osx
ser = serial.Serial(device, 115200, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)

bytes = ser.read(500)

splitby = 11
for i in range(splitby):
    offset = i
    for i in range(len(bytes)//splitby):
        datum = bytes[i*splitby+offset:(i+1)*splitby+offset]
        float = datum[2:6]
        float = struct.unpack('!f',float)
        print(float)
```

And given the plot above, and the example in the data file, I'm expecting a float a sensible maybe -100 to +100 range.

But I just get complete gibberish:

```
(5.502899069403557e-41,)
(-2.350988701644575e-38,)
(33.033477783203125,)
(1.408765983841204e-38,)
(0.0,)
(9.839021882302715e-36,)
(-1.1925119585221935e-23,)
(0.0,)
(1.9816933148201242e-21,)
(4.0218751556765575e+23,)
(0.0,)
(98320384.0,)
(-1.894110546575914e-13,)
```

The reason for the outer loop was I wanted to see if I could make sense of the data by offsetting it by up to 11 bytes (as I wondered if maybe I was starting to poll the device in the middle of an 11 byte section), but regardless the data is nonsense.

Does anyone have any advice how I might make sense of the data?

An example byte string of 500 length is:

```
b'\xaaUA\xd4,\xc0\xbbL\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd5\x15\xed\xbbM\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd0p\x84\xbbN\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xcd\xb3)\xbbO\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xc4\xb74\xbbP\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xca\x118\xbbQ\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xcf(A\xbbR\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd6f\x0f\xbbS\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd5\x8f\x97\xbbT\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd0)\xb3\xbbU\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xcd-\xd9\xbbV\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xcf\x1f\\\xbbW\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd6\xbf\xf9\xbbX\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd90\xed\xbbY\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xddp\x15\xbbZ\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd7\x91c\xbb[\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd4$\xad\xbb\\\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xcf\x88\xa9\xbb]\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xcf\xa9\x18\xbb^\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xce\xae{\xbb_\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xcc\x89+\xbb`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd0\x08\x83\xbba\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd4\xdb\xb5\xbbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd95a\xbbc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd70\xa8\xbbd\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd3#`\xbbe\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xcd\xa4]\xbbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xcd\xa0L\xbbg\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xcd\xe5\xd7\xbbh\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xce\xd5\xec\xbbi\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xcd;#\xbbj\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xcd'
```

**ADDENDUM:** Sorry I wasn't clear. It starts off working ok, but then fails. For example, if I use the byte string above, we start off with good data:

```
(26.5218505859375,)
```

But this promptly descends into:

```
(1.408765983841204e-38,)
(0.0,)
(-16140921856.0,)
(-1.1925119585221935e-23,)
(0.0,)
(-1.0772448149509728e-05,)
(4.021874795388587e+23,)
(0.0,)
```

**ADDENDUM:** The marked answer below is fine, but in the interim I came up with my own solution using regex which seems to work perfectly fine:

```
class PLD():
    def __init__(self, device='COM5'):

        self.device = device        # self.device = '/dev/cu.usbserial-DM003616' #osx
        self.sample_rate = 1/0.0256
        self.ser = serial.Serial(device, 115200, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)

    def get_data(self,n=500):
        regexp = '\\xaa.+?\\xbb'
        floats = []
        serial_data = self.ser.read(n)
        for match in re.findall(regexp, serial_data):
            serial_data = match[2:6]
            try:
                datum = struct.unpack('!f', serial_data)[0]
                floats.append(datum)
            except struct.error:
                floats.append(0)
        return floats
```

Comment: It looks like the data is there: I can see the 0xaa, 0x55 header followed by 0x41, 0xd4, 0x2c, 0xc0 followed by the 0xbb tag and count, six zeroes followed by footer bytes 0x99, 0x66.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you are relying on never losing part of a transmission or getting any corruption, both of those are flawed assumptions.
you need to implement a wait/check for the header bytes, and ideally the same for the footer bytes:

```
#!python3
import struct

class FakeSerial():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = b'\xaaUA\xd4,\xc0\xbbL\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd5\x15\xed\xbbM\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd0p\x84\xbbN\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xcd\xb3)\xbbO\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xc4\xb74\xbbP\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xca\x118\xbbQ\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xcf(A\xbbR\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd6f\x0f\xbbS\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd5\x8f\x97\xbbT\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd0)\xb3\xbbU\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xcd-\xd9\xbbV\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xcf\x1f\\\xbbW\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd6\xbf\xf9\xbbX\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd90\xed\xbbY\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xddp\x15\xbbZ\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd7\x91c\xbb[\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd4$\xad\xbb\\\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xcf\x88\xa9\xbb]\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xcf\xa9\x18\xbb^\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xce\xae{\xbb_\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xcc\x89+\xbb`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd0\x08\x83\xbba\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd4\xdb\xb5\xbbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd95a\xbbc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd70\xa8\xbbd\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xd3#`\xbbe\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xcd\xa4]\xbbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xcd\xa0L\xbbg\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xcd\xe5\xd7\xbbh\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xce\xd5\xec\xbbi\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f\xaaUA\xcd;#\xbbj\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99f'
        self.index = 0

    def read(self, num=1):
        data = self.data[self.index : self.index+num]
        self.index += num
        if self.index > len(self.data):
            self.index = 0
        return data

s = FakeSerial()

while True:
    if s.read() == b'\xaa': # wait for header 1 because of loop
        if s.read() == b'\x55': # check  header 1 followed immediately by header 2
            data = s.read(4) # get the data
            print(struct.unpack('!f',data)) # unpack it

            # choose one of these methods, not both
            # 1
            padding = s.read(10) # this should read the tag, count, reserved and footer bytes

            # 2
            # this instead loops waiting for footer bytes
#           while True: 
#               if s.read() == b'\x99': # footer 1
#                   if s.read() == b'\x66': # footer 2
#                       break
```

I made a fake serial class so I could write an example closer to how you actually need to use it, so you can ignore that bit, note however that i removed a few bytes from the end of your example code as it was an incomplete data frame.

the output of this was:

```
(26.5218505859375,)
(26.635705947875977,)
(26.05493927001953,)
(25.712480545043945,)
(24.589454650878906,)
(25.258407592773438,)
(25.894655227661133,)
(26.799833297729492,)
(26.695112228393555,)
(26.020360946655273,)
(25.64738655090332,)
(25.89031219482422,)
(26.84373664855957,)
(27.148889541625977,)
(27.67972755432129,)
(26.94598960876465,)
(26.517908096313477,)
(25.941728591918945,)
(25.957565307617188,)
(25.835195541381836,)
(25.56697654724121,)
(26.0041561126709,)
(26.60727882385254,)
(27.151063919067383,)
(26.898757934570312,)
(26.39227294921875,)
(25.70525550842285,)
(25.703269958496094,)
(25.737226486206055,)
(25.854454040527344,)
(25.65387535095215,)
```

Comment: I had actually come up with a solution myself using regex but your method is also perfectly fine.

Comment: it comes down to what your criteria are, regex would use more cpu power but if fast enough for your purposes then thats perfectly fine, both methods 1 and 2 in my answer above are working on the assumption that missing some data frames is fine (but would happen in different ways) with the second one having the potential to freeze up (infinite loop) but the first one not validating that the entire frame is received intact. ideally you would also extract count, reserved and footer bytes to validate the frame, and i believe by tracking the `count` you would be able to check if you missed a frame

Answer (score 0):

Does this data look right?

```
by=b'\x41\xd4\x2c\xc0'
print(list(by))
print(struct.unpack('!f',by))
```

Output:

```
[65, 212, 44, 192]
(26.5218505859375,)
```

I have looked at your data and according to the format info you supply the first packet seems to encode a float of 26.521 ...

Also, the sample data they supply seems to decode correctly:

```
by=b'\xc0\x59\x99\x99'
print(list(by))
print(struct.unpack('!f',by))
```

Output:

```
[192, 89, 153, 153]
(-3.3999998569488525,)
```

In general terms you need to write some software which reads each byte in turn and when you find a 0xaa byte, read the next 15 bytes also and check that all the constant bytes are in the right places: ([0xaa,0x55]....[0xbb].[0,0,0,0,0,0,0x99,0x66]) and then you can pass bytes 2..5 through `unpack()`.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I wasn't clear. The code works for the first sample but then fails.

Comment: So, does my answer contain advice on how to make sense of the data?